# Create javascript property like C# property

Tags: c#, javascript

Is it possible to create a property on a javascript object that behaves similar to a property in C#.

Example:
I've created an auto-sizing textarea widget using dojo.  In order to get the "value" property out of my widget, I've hooked up to the onchange event and I'm setting a variable everytime the value of the textarea changes.

Is there a way to accomplish this without hooking up to the onchange event.

**Edit**

In other words, is it possible to write something in JavaScript that behaves like getters and/or setters.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible in ECMAScript 5 implementations, which include [recent versions of all major browsers](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/). The ECMAScript 5 spec adds standardized getters and setters. One quirk is that IE 8 has this feature, but only on DOM nodes. This is what the syntax looks like:

```
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, "value", {
    get: function () {
        return this.val;
    },
    set: function(val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
});
```

There has also been a proprietary implementation of getters and setters in Mozilla for a long time that was also later adopted by WebKit and Opera but this is not available in IE.

Comment: this looks like what I was looking for, but how do you call it when you want to use it in the code?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what you're asking here.  You can always get the value of a textarea without the onchange event.  you'd have to get the object then look at the value property.

for example, if your textarea has an id="mytext" you can do

```
var mytextarea = document.getElementById("mytext");
var text = mytextarea.value;
```

Comment: That much I know John.  Thank you.  I've edited my question. I hope it is a little more clear now.

Comment: it doesn't seem any clearer to me.  Are you looking to add logic to the property getter and setter?